# Laravel Livewire Rappasoft - Hide the ID column but pass it in the action column

Tags: datatable, livewire-3

If i include the `Column::make("ID", "id"),` the code works correctly and the ID is passed in the action column, However I do not want to display the IDs of each user in the dataTable.

```
    return [
        // Exclude the ID column from the table
        Column::make("ID", "id"),
        Column::make("Name", "name")
            ->sortable()
            ->searchable(),

        Column::make("Email", "email")
            ->sortable()
            ->searchable(),
        // Add ID to the Action column for reference
        Column::make('Action')
            ->label(
                fn ($row, Column $column) => view('livewire.datatables.action-column', [
                    'user' => $row,
                    'column' => $column,
                ])
            )->HTML(),
    ];
```

So if I remove the `Column::make("ID", "id"),` I get a `Missing required parameter for [Route: user.view] [URI: user/view/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].` error.

```
<div>
    <a wire:nagivate href="{{ route('user.view', ['id' => $user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"
        title="View this record"><i class="lni lni-eye"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" title="View this record"><i class="bx bx-pencil"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" title="View this record"><i class="bx bx-trash"></i></a>
</div>
```